# Change the Default Role when Adding Contact Roles to Opportunity

Tags: administration, opportunity, contact, default-value

I am new to being a Salesforce admin, and am going to a few classes in the coming weeks.  Currently I am trying to find where to set the default value for Contact Roles when adding them to an opportunity that was created without a contact.

So now when people go and click on New next to Contact Roles on an opportunity it loads up a list of all the people who work or are attached to the account the opportunity was created under but their default value is not set to None.  This means that ALL of them will be added unless you manually go and change each Role to "None".  This makes it a huge pain when there are 10-20-50 contacts listed under the account.

I found a question from 4 years ago on Success.Salesforce.com but no answer on where to set the Role default was found.

[image: No Contact Roles On Opportunity]

[image: Defaults to adding them all]

So you can see it defaults to Economic Buyer not None.  This means in this case this account has 50 users, so anytime you want to add a new contact you have to go through and change the role to None on up-to 50 Contacts you don't want added to that opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this.  You will have to change the default back to "--None--" and get your users in the habit of adding the role when they create an opportunity from a contact.  With a good bit of custom code you could make a button and visualforce page with a bit of extra functionality that you would normally see on the "New Contact Role" page.

---

INCORRECT:

This is not functionality currently available, but you may vote for the idea on the Salesforce IdeaExchange here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000JF16AAG

I'd encourage you to spend time on the IdeaExchange and vote for functionality that you would like to see.  Salesforce constantly tries to keep up with the ideas from its users.  You can see ideas that have been implemented here: [https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?sort=2&filter=Delivered+in+Winter+15](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch?sort=2&filter=Delivered%20in%20Winter%2015)

--Edit---
I realized I didn't completely answer your question.  Only contacts that you select a role for on that page will be added as Contact Roles.  If you keep them as "--None--" they will not be added.

Comment: I'm not sure that question is the same problem.  That said it did lead me to where the default is set, and it looks like "None" is not a default option.  Thus it looks like some sort of custom button needs to be created to set the values to "None" so they don't have to manually click None on each contact they don't want to be added.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I don't completely understand.  You have a default value set for ContactRole.  When the ContactRole page comes up, a user will have to manually change each role to "--None--" to prevent them from being added as a ContactRole?  You want to know if there is a way to have a default, but have the ability to override that default when necessary?

Comment: Yeah, I added some photos to better explain.

Comment: I understand now!  I apologize for my incorrect answer.

Comment: Turned off the old Default Value and it is not set to None!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you . https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contactroles.htm

Thanks,
Tamil.